# Git pull --mirror with concurent changes

Tags: git, version-control

I have a remote repository that I wish to mirror-clone for local development reasons. I wish to allow a local Team of developers to use the local clone to do their work, and then allow the clone to push up the refs to the original authoritive git repository.

Is it possible to also allow commits to the original repository at the same time, while rebasing the commits on the local non-authoritave clone? What would the local developers have to do to to their local (regular) cloned repositories to account for the rebase of the original repository refs?

Comment: If the remote repo is non-empty, you'd better not use git pull/push with --mirror option. Why don'y you merge the changes of the local git repo to the remote repo and let developers clone the remote repo and work on it?

Comment: The reason I cannot do that is because I want to Bypass Access restrictions of the Network the remote repo is hosted on. So basically developers can commit to a "middle" repo and then a developer can commit the refs to the "remote" repo

Comment: So what's the process you are using: mirror clone the non-authoritive repo -> add the mirror cloned repo as another remote for your local repo -> make changes -> push to authoritive repo? And what do you mean "Is it possible to also allow commits to the original repository at the same time, while rebasing the commits on the local non-authoritave clone"? In a certian local repo, you should commit or rebase one by one.

Comment: Essentially I would imagine doing the following:
Mirror clone (bare) from authoritive repo to create non-authoritave repo
Developers clone Non-authoritave repo and push to/pull from this repo
When all developers are done with the Project, push non-Authoritive repo changes to authoritiave repo

Would changes to authoritiave repo be allowed during this process (while developers are working with non-authoritave repo)?

Comment: That sounds reasonable. And just for suggestion: before pushing changes to authoritiave repo, you'd better merge all developers' changes into one branch, and push the only one branch into authoritiave repo.